# axios does not post form data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have this function in a vue.js registration component

```
register: function () {
  console.log('username,passwor,email', this.username, this.password, this.email);
      axios.post( this.BASE_URL + "/api/register", {
      email: this.email,
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password,
    }).then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

And here is the registration form:

```
<form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

<div id="signupalert" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger">
    <p>Error:</p>
    <span></span>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">email</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"  v-model="email"  placeholder="email">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-md-3 control-label">username</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" v-model="username"  placeholder="username">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">password</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" v-model="password"  placeholder="password">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <!-- Button -->                                        
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <button @click="register()" id="btn-signup" type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right" ></i> Register</button>                                        
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

The strange thing is that when the function is called, I can see in the console that `'username`,`passwor`,`email` values are logged in the console. But in the backend, the received fields in the posted form are empty.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Can you show your controller ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'controller'?

Comment: change `{
      email: this.email,
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password,
    }` to `{
      'email': this.email,
      'username': this.username,
      'password': this.password,
    }` becouse you have to make correct syntax of json

Comment: @CaShiS actually I realised that the backend expects form fields not json data. So  how can change it to receive the post as an html form?

Comment: console.log prevent by ie edge browser. which browser you are using ?

Comment: @hsyn Chromium.

Comment: Open developer toolbar and click Console tab. Post again. What is the error message there ?

Comment: Show your backend code

Comment: @CaShiS it's in golang, and I'm reluctant to change it. So wondering how to make post as a conventional html form?

Comment: If you want to do it with page reload you can submit your form traditionally `<button type="submit" on:click="signUpForm">Search</button> ` `methods: {submitForm: function() {
      document.getElementById("searchForm").submit();
 }}`

Comment: Isn't it possible to submit form using axios?

Comment: Try to use `var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "username");` and then send it vie axios `axios.post( this.BASE_URL + "/api/register", formData)`